# Setting Up PostgreSQL for Rails on a Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, passwords, postgresql-9.1

I just recently installed postgresql for mac [with this](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx).
The problem I get, however, is that I never stated a password for the user 'postgres' but this seems vitally necessary to do anything with postgresql.

Comment: I gather you've read the [installation guide](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide)?

Comment: Hmm, It doesn't prompt me to do the middle part (setup a password and other settings). Is there a way to completely remove postgresql?

Comment: Thank you, I realized I had made a mistake, complete uninstalled and then reinstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, you do not need to completely reinstall, you can change the password with:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '<newPassword>';
```

Comment: And you do not need the current password to do so?

Comment: @Planetpluto I believe that as long as you are running the command as a privileged user, you should be fine.  So if the superuser doesn't have a password, as long as your are logged into that account then this should still work, yes.  Please correct me if this does not turn out to be the case.